# How to put List in to the comboBox AddRange?

Tags: c#, list, combobox

I have this List:

```
public static List<int> getData(OdbcConnection conn)
{
    List<int> myData = new List<int>();
    string myQuery = "some Sql text";
    // ...............some other code
    return myData;
}
```

And I need to add parameters from the List to the comboBox with AddRange:

`this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange( new object[] { ??????????? });`

How should I make it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(getData(conn).ToArray());